# Strange JS or CSS (Can't figure out which one makes issue) related issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, layout

Please visit [this link](http://vefaestetik.az/?debug).

When I open it on chrome or firefox and refresh multiple times I'm getting following screen:

[image]

I really can't understand why this problem happens. Also, no error in firebug on both browsers: Chrome and Firefox. Any suggestions?

Comment: Chrome calculates `#front-slides` as having no height, Firefox stretches the element, I am looking into why.

Comment: @A.M.K firefox gave me same error after multiple refresh. So both browsers have same problem

Comment: Please see my answer, I think the reason is that your images haven't finished loading before their container's height gets calculated from them.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving `#front-slides` a height (370px in this case) and setting it to `overflow: hidden;`, then removing the overflow on `.slides_container`.

This seems to fix the issue for me, the problem appears to have been that `.slides_control`'s height is being set wrong, apparently it's set to the images height before they have loaded.

Your other solution would be to manually set `.slides_control`'s height to 370px or change the calculation till after the page has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

the height for dom element with class "slides_control" is getting set dynamically.

Sometimes it is 18px , but in other cases it is 370px.

If you set the height explicitly to 370 px, it works , but you may want to look into it further as to why in your code it is setting different values.

Comment: As I explain in my answer, this is most likely because the images that it's surrounding haven't finished loading before `.slides_control`'s height gets calculated from them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your functions (related with slider) fires before all images load. Move the, into `window.onload` like below

```
window.onload = function () {
    //##########################################
    // Front slides
    //##########################################

    $('#front-slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        preloadImage: 'design/img/elems/loading.gif',
        generateNextPrev: false,
        play: 5000,
        pause: 2500,
        hoverPause: true,
        animationStart: function(current){
            $("#headline h6").fadeOut("slow");
        },
        animationComplete: function(current){
            $slideCaption = $(".slides_container div.slide:eq("+ (current-1) +") .caption").text();
            $("#headline h6").text($slideCaption);
            if($slideCaption != ''){
                $("#headline h6").fadeIn("slow");
            }else{
                $("#headline").hide("slow");
            }
        }

    });

    // default headline
    $firstCaption = $(".slides_container div.slide:eq(0) .caption").text();
    if($firstCaption != ''){
        $("#headline h6").text($firstCaption);
    }else{
        $("#headline").hide();
    }

}
```